# skorks/omniauth-linkedin unable to retrieve 'company field' under positions hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, linkedin-api

I'm having difficulty retrieving the company field from the positions hash. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong. I'm not having issues with other fields or the profile image.

omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, "xyz", "abc", :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress ', :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "location", "positions"]
end
```

user.rb

```
def self.create_user_from_linkedin(auth)
    create(

    avatar: process_uri(auth['info']['image'] + "?width=9999"),
    email: auth['info']['email'],
    provider: auth['provider'],
    uid: auth['uid'],
    name: auth['info']['name'],
    gender: auth['info']['first_name'],
    #date_of_birth: "
    #location: auth['info']['location'],
    position: auth['extra']['raw_info']['positions'],
    bio: auth['extra']['raw_info']['headline']


    )
end
```

Comment: Are you receiving a particular error code in response to the request?  You didn't elaborate at all on what the difficulty you're having was.  "r_fullprofile" is no longer a publicly available permission, so perhaps you just don't have the permission you need to make the request you're attempting to make?

Comment: Hi Justin,  I appreciate your feedback. The issue I'm having is - while I'm getting data back for the rest of the fields, I'm not getting any data for the field 'positions.' Furthermore, I've tried using the 'r_basicprofile', but no luck. 'Positions' field is listed under basic profile, thus I'm not sure whether this is an authorization issue. Also, I don't get any error, it's just that the field 'positions' does not get populated.